# iPhone : webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType timing problem

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have a WebView which is loading and HTML String and I want it to catch clicks on links.
For that I need to use the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType method.
The problem is that this method gets called multiple times before the HTML content is fully loaded and I only want to start catching clicks at that moment.
The question is how to know when the HTML content is fully loaded ? I thought it was simple so I created a boolean as an iVar of the ViewController containing the WebView and I set it to YES after calling loadHTMLString. Then, in webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType I was testing if that boolean was true and if it was the case I was outputting something like "OK". But "OK" was appearing without clicking on a link => fail.

Any idea on how I could make this work ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` delegate method to know when the HTML is loaded.

But I'd rather use another solution:
In `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` you can filter requests by navigation type:

```
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    // Catch links

    return NO; // if you want to cancel the request, else YES
}
```

Comment: I didn't know I was kind of reinventing the wheel with my boolean. I'll definitely use the navigationType variable now, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViews{
}
```

this method will callwhen the HTML content is fully loaded.
it may helps you.

Comment: I should have found it by myself (I guess I was looking for something more complicated...), thank you.